# Span position absolute is not centered with top and left

Tags: css

I want to create a "X" with css spans and position absolute, but the spans aren't centered even if they should.

The container has the `font-size` of `1px`. and a `height` and `width` of `100em`. Therefore I can use `1em` as 1% of the parents size.

I used `transform-origin: 0px 5em;` on the span, to rotate it without changing the starting point. The Element starts in 20% `top` and `left` (20em) and ends in `80%` (top and left).

To get the required `width` i simply calculated: `Square root( square of (60) * 2)` (Pythagorean theorem) (60 because start and end 20 -- 100-20*2)

But for some reason the X is clearly not centered. Do you know what i did wrong?

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
.check
{
    font-size: 1px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100em;
    width: 100em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red inset;
}



.check span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 10em;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    transition:.3s;
}
.check.red span
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    transform-origin: 0px 5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 20em;
    left: 20em;
}
.check.red span:nth-of-type(2)
{
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 20em;
    left: 80em;
}





.check.red:hover span
{
    width: 84.852813742em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="check red">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is here, but you also used transform origin. once rotated to compensate , edge that are going down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an automatic solution, but changing some values in your css i solved it:

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
.check
{
    font-size: 1px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100em;
    width: 100em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red inset;
}



.check span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 10em;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    transition:.3s;
}
.check.red span
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    transform-origin: 0px 5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 18em;
    left: 22em;
}
.check.red span:nth-of-type(2)
{
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 18em;
    left: 78em;
}





.check.red:hover span
{
    width: 78em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="check red">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I changed some values till it looked better ^^
 mark my answer if i solved your problem

Comment: Ok. But can you also add that its not a perfect solution? because it fixes the problem but doesnt help to avoid it when creating other shapes

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to make life easier here.

Firstly you can transform origin using a percentage, which means you don't need to calculate it yourself.
You can also position using a percentage, then offset using a transform (again with a percentage) to center no matter the size.
You can also set the width of the cross using a percentage, which will take it size from its parent.

Update:
Change the cross to animate from the top, rather than the center by using background gradients.

```css
.check
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red inset;
}

.check span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 0%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, red 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: left bottom;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}
.check.red span
{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.check.red span:last-child
{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.check.red:hover span
{
    background-position: right bottom;
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="check red">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: But is it also possible to make the animation more like someone writes a X? Originially my second span had `.3s` delay.This way it looked like someone wrote two lines (both from top) to create a X (your animation starts form the center)

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the animation starting from the top, rather than the center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
use `margin-top:-0.5rem;`

```
.check span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 10em;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    transition:.3s; margin-top:-0.5rem;
}
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
.check
{
    font-size: 1px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100em;
    width: 100em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red inset;
   
}



.check span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 10em;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    transition:.3s; margin-top:-0.5rem;
}
.check.red span
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    transform-origin: 0px 5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 20em;
    left: 20em;
}
.check.red span:nth-of-type(2)
{
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 20em;
    left: 80em;
}





.check.red:hover span
{
    width: 84.852813742em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="check red">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is still not centered

Comment: what do you mean centered ?

Comment: The distance between the span element and the parent border. on your snippet the distance on the top is way shorter. (at least in firefox and chrome)